# How to use PHP variable in HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a custom Dialog box that will take a one-dimensional array as a variable, create a radio button for each item in the array, and return the index of the user's selection back to the .gs file, using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile. I don't know how to get the radio buttons to take a variable as their id, name, or value. My current code of course just returns "i" no matter what the user selects. How do I get a variable inside the  brackets? I'm getting errors if I try to use script brackets or php brackets. Is there a simpler way?

I leaned heavily on the following two tutorials, if that helps at all: 
https://yagisanatode.com/2018/06/10/google-apps-script-getting-input-data-from-a-dialog-box-in-google-sheets/, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TRXL7TbCSI from Jordan Rhea

Help?

```js
function test(){ 
//Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Radio_Template')
  var myArray = ["apple","banana","kiwi"]; //for testing purposes. Will otherwise be a variable array passed to test()
  var myTitle = "Select your favorite fruit"; //for testing purposes. Will otherwise be a variable string passed to test()
      html.myArray = myArray;
       var html = html.evaluate().setHeight(200);//Later I'll make the height dependent on Array.length
  
  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, myTitle);
 
};

function runsies(value){
  //Display the values submitted from the dialog box in the Logger. 
  Logger.log(value);
  Logger.log("test that we got to runsies")
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(value)
//SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue(values)
//sometimes I use the above, logger always says: No functions have been run in this editor session.       
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    
    <? for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 
    ?>
      <div>
      
        <input type="radio" id="i" name="selection" value="i">
        <label for=i><?= myArray[i] ?></label><br>
   
      </div>
    
    <? } ?>
  
  <br>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" >
    </div>
  </body>
  
<script>
      function form_data(){
        var value = $("input[name=selection]:checked").val();
             
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().runsies(value);
        google.script.host.close();
      };
      
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not fix everything, but it will generate the radio input fields correctly.

```
  <? for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){ 
    ?>
      <div>

        <input type="radio" id="<?= myArray[i] ?>" name="selection" value="<?= myArray[i] ?>">
        <label for=<?= myArray[i] ?>></label><br>

      </div>

    <? } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! That was exactly what I was missing. I'm trying to re-learn some of this after a break of 10 years, and it's not always easy going.